# azure ci cd tomcat error. Error : 2021-04-22T04:58:28.6149523Z ##[error]Error: /usr/bin/curl failed with return code: 22

Tags: java, tomcat, curl, azure-devops, return-code

I am trying to deploy my web application on tomcat server. I am using azure CI CD pipeline. I have build the code and generated war file in azure artifacts. I am using the self hosted agent for cd pipeline and installed tomcat on it. for cd pipeline, I added deploy to tomcat server as task, however I am getting below error:
As a part of troubleshooting checked curl availability and added curl in capabilities of agent. Added manager-gui role in tomcat-users.xml file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0DrW.jpg)
error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clEUx.jpg)

Can someone please provide the solution.

Comment: What URL are you trying to access? Maybe it's not the `manager-gui` roles, but one of the others, that you need. Or maybe you didn't add the role correctly. Or you're logging in with the wrong user or password, e.g. the `curl` command seems to have the password hardcoded as `password`.

Comment: hi Andreas, I am trying to access is  http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/_helshabiniproject1&update=true (mentioned in build error screenshot ) added the below in tomcat-users.xml.<role rolename="manager-gui/">
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username ="tomcat" password="password" roles="manager-gui"/>
<user username="deployer" password="deployer" roles="manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>

Comment: *"mentioned in build error screenshot"* No it isn't.

Comment: If the curl command is accessing the text interface (/manager/text/), it requires role `manager-script`. Only user `deployer` has that role, and it has password `deployer`, but the curl command specifies an unknown user name with password `password`, so why are you surprised to get `401 Unauthorized`?

Comment: I tried with credentials as username: deployer and password: deployer, however still facing the same error.